# Access css class from css file from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Is there anyway to access a css class that is located in a css file, and add and remove styles from it.

Edit:

What i am trying to achieve for now, is that i have added a css file "customize", and i have added a css class in it:

```
    .yafheader
{
    display:none;
}
```

I just want to manipulate the display value, that is all.

Comment: Any reason not to use javascript for this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the simplest solution is to just put the CSS you want in the stylesheet with a new class name, and then at runtime apply that class name to the element(s) you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Create two CSS rules - one to display and one not to display. Then create a property of your class for CSS and apply the CSS rule via the property.

Answer (score 0):

Code behind is executed on the server side. So it may be possible to get the CSS class parsed and manipulate it, but you need a plan on how this manipulated object is supposed to be injected into your output. One thing you might do would be to write a new css file with your manipulated class. There might be more convenient ways of doing that however; I believe it might help if you give a bit more context about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to modify the css file itself because it can be accessed by many users simultaneously.  if you change the underlying css file in response to an action by your first site visitor, the next site visitor to load the page will receive the new css file, with styles that reflect the actions of the other user on your site. do as others have suggested and define 2 classes, and add/remove the appropriate classes at runtime using javascript.